# GNU make: “Nothing to be done for 'target'” vs. “'target' is up to date”

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How does GNU make decide which of the messages to emit? The Makefile I am using causes *Nothing to be done for 'target'* messages to be emitted when the target is up do date. But I think *'target' is up to date* would be more appropriate.

Comment: Why is this an issue? Do you want a suggestion on how to patch `make`?

Comment: "Nothing to be done" is probably more accurate from `make`s point of view. All it knows is dependencies. No dependency is newer than the target, so there's "nothing to be done".

Comment: It isn't an issue. I am just curious.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The chief difference is in whether gmake has a rule to build the target or not.  If there is no rule for the target, but the target exists, then gmake will say, "Nothing to be done", as in, "I don't know how to update this thing, but it already exists, so I guess there's nothing to be done."  If there is a rule, but the target is already up-to-date, then gmake will say, "is up to date", as in, "I do have instructions for updating this thing, but it appears to already be up-to-date, so I'm not going to do anything."

Here's a concrete example:

```
$ echo "upToDate: older ; @echo done" > Makefile
$ touch older ; sleep 2 ; touch upToDate ; touch nothingToDo
$ ls --full-time -l older upToDate nothingToDo
-rw-r--r-- 1 ericm ericm 0 2011-04-20 11:13:04.970243002 -0700 nothingToDo
-rw-r--r-- 1 ericm ericm 0 2011-04-20 11:13:02.960243003 -0700 older
-rw-r--r-- 1 ericm ericm 0 2011-04-20 11:13:04.960243001 -0700 upToDate
$ gmake upToDate
gmake: `upToDate' is up to date.
$ gmake nothingToDo
gmake: Nothing to be done for `nothingToDo'.
```

Since gmake has no rule for "nothingToDo", but the file already exists, you get the "nothing to be done" message.  If "nothingToDo" did not exist, you would instead get the familiar, "No rule to make" message.

In contrast, because gmake has a rule for "upToDate", and the file appears to be up-to-date, you get the "is up to date" message.

Comment: This is not quite right, if you add `all: upToDate`, then `make all` produces the same message as `make nothingToDo`.

Comment: @o11c it's fundamentally the same thing, really:  gmake has no instructions regarding how to build "all" so it says "nothing to do".

Comment: @EricMelski but it's not an error when it doesn't exist in that case.

Comment: @o11c please feel free to submit your own answer if you feel mine is so terribly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I research this problem, and test a lot of scenes, the result I got is:

If the target has no recipe and if no any prerequisites' recipes are executed, then `Nothing to be done for "top target"` will printed

If the target has recipe, but the recipe is not executed, then `is up to date` is printed.

If no rules for a existing file, and make that existing file as target also print `Nothing to be done for "xxx"`