# make wildcard target always get Nothing to be done

Tags: windows, gcc, cmd, makefile, msys2

I wrote a makefile which contains some wildcard target for building and running.
My makefile contents are the following.

```
ALL_EXES=$(shell ls *.exe 2>/dev/null)
.PHONY:  all clean $(ALL_EXES) foo

CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -Wall
GTKFLAGS=$(shell pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0)
GTKLIBS=$(shell pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)
PWD=$(shell pwd)

clean:
    @echo cleanning
    $(shell sh -c "rm *.exe 2>/dev/null")

%: %.c
    $(CC) $(GTKFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(GTKLIBS) $(CFLAGS) 

%.exe: %
    @echo running $@
    $(shell sh -c "$(PWD)/$@")
```

I can run `make some-program` successfully, but Nothing to be done for 'some-program.exe' is always occurs when I run `make some-program.exe`.

Comment: I read [gnu-make-nothing-to-be-done-for-target-vs-target-is-up-to-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734158/gnu-make-nothing-to-be-done-for-target-vs-target-is-up-to-date) and know what's the meaning of `Nothing to be done for ...`, but from the makefile I do provide the prerequsites and build rules for wildcard exe files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, my workaround makefile is the followings.

```
ALL_EXES=$(shell ls *.exe 2>/dev/null)
.PHONY:  all clean

CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -Wall
GTKFLAGS=$(shell pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0)
GTKLIBS=$(shell pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)
PWD=$(shell pwd)

clean:
    @echo cleanning $(shell ls *.exe 2>/dev/null)
    $(shell sh -c "rm *.exe 2>/dev/null")

%.exe: %.c
    @echo building $<
    $(CC) $(GTKFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(GTKLIBS) $(CFLAGS) 

run_%.exe: %.exe
    @echo running $<
    $(PWD)/$<

example-stack.exe: example-stack.c stack.c
    $(CC) -I. -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `%: %.c` should be `%.exe: %.c` , because that is the rule for creating a `.exe` file based on a `.c` source.

The line `%.exe: %` should be something else, e.g. `run: foo.exe` .